# c++ call functions in copy constructor

Tags: c++, class

I currently have

```
public:
    LargerSetPartD(unsigned maxValue);
    LargerSetPartD(const LargerSetPartD &);  //copy constructor
    void printElements();               // prints members
    void set_union(const LargerSetPartD &);
    bool isMember(unsigned int);
private:
    unsigned long Values;
    unsigned maxElementValues;
```

In set_union
I am trying to do

```
LargerSetPartD *temparray = new LargerSetPartD(maxElementValue);
//this part of the code just saves an old array composed of Values to temparray.
if ( tempArray->isMember(i) || other.isMember(i))
```

However other.isMember(i) is not working. I also tried other->isMember(i) and that doesnt work. I can not touch/change the public functions so I cant add const in is member. im not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. The error message i get is

```
passing ‘const LargerSetPartD’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

copy constructor:
LargerSetPartD::LargerSetPartD(const LargerSetPartD &other)
{

        Values = other.Values;
        maxElementValue = other.maxElementValue;
}
```

Comment: `Values` is a `long`, it's a fundemental type that has no members to call.

Comment: With the -> operator after Values you're treating Values as if it's a pointer, but it's a long, probably an int.

Comment: You need to either drop `const` from `set_union(const LargerSetPartD &)` or add `const` to `isMember()`. Adding `const` to `isMember()` should be a fairly invisible change with respect to the public interface.

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Besides the sanity of trying to invoke a non-existent member from a `unsigned long`, `other.isMember()` is not working is entirely reasonable (and including, and researching, the resulting error message would probably have been educational). `isMember` is not `const`, but `other` *is*. Invoking non-const members from a const object is not allowed. It is *highly* likely `isMember` not only *can* be `const`, but *should* be `const`. Making it so would fix your problem. *"I can not touch/change the public functions"* - that's a shame, because that's what's required.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean to add values there! It is supose to be temparray which I have now fixed!

Comment: @Continuum - Adding `[Solved]` to the subject is not the correct way to mark a question solved. Rather you should click the check mark next to the answer you find solved the problem the best. It is perfectly fine to add your own answer (as an answer, not as part of the question) and mark *that* answer, if you solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `other` is the `const LargerSetPartD &` argument to `set_union`, you are trying to call a non-`const` method on a `const` object, which is not permitted.

Since you can't change the signature of the public methods, you could create a temporary non-const copy of `other` and call the method on that:

```cpp
LargerSetPartD tmp_other(other);
if ( tempArray->isMember(i) || tmp_other.isMember(i))
    ...
```

Comment: The instructons state that I can not touch the public class. So I feel like I must be doing something wrong when I initialize my copy constructor.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to the copy constructor?

Comment: @Continuum you're not doing something wrong. The copy ctor should take a const-reference. Whether `set_union` is proper only you can say, but if it's invoked from the copy-ctor, it too must take a `const` reference. Whoever (a) established that `isMember` is *not* `const`, and (b) seemingly mandated it be called from a `const` context, is the person(s) responsible for the woes you're feeling right now. If that person is a prof, tell them. If it is a co-worker, berate them (just kidding =). If it is *you*, well.. yeah.

Comment: @Continuum you could make a temporary copy of `other` and call `isMember` on that, in addition to the temporary object you're already creating.

Comment: You are actually correct! I just tried that right now and it worked!

Comment: I have added that suggestion as an edit. You could accept this answer if you found it helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I can not touch/change the public functions...

This means you need to do some hack and bypass the compiler's checks. If you were allowed to fix your code, you would qualify your `isMember` method with `const`, like this:

```
public:
...
    bool isMember(unsigned int) const;
```

Assuming this would be valid (that is, assuming `isMember` really doesn't change the object it works on, which makes sense taking into account the method's name), you can "fake" this without changing the header file. Use `const_cast` like this:

```
tempArray->isMember(i) // error

const_cast<LargerSetPartD*>(tempArray)->isMember(i) // OK
```

and like this:

```
other.isMember(i) // error

const_cast<LargerSetPartD&>(other.isMember(i)) // OK
```

However, this opens your code to future problems (undefined behavior) - the compiler will now not stop you from changing stuff in your `isMember` method. Also, the code looks ugly. So better add `const` where needed.

---

In addition, the compiler offers you a much more powerful (and dangerous) alternative:

> ... [-fpermissive]

If you add `-fpermissive` to your compilation command line, the compiler will ignore all `const` qualifiers. This will almost surely hide dangerous bugs (which you don't want to do), so use this method only if absolutely needed.